# Travis CI - Cannot restore packages via "nuget restore"

Tags: mono, nuget, travis-ci

I'm very new to Travis CI but I cannot get why nuget cannot restore packages on my project. It doesn't give any error output, just blank output with no packages downloaded.

Also, I tested it and it is working fine on Linux/MacOS. Does anyone had similar problem and is able to tell me what's wrong?

Here is Travis CI project: https://travis-ci.org/stanislavromanov/backoff

Same project on GitHub: https://github.com/stanislavromanov/backoff

Answer (score 1):

Your sln/project worked fine for me ;-)

Try the following for your yml file to do some basic debugging on Travis. This way you can at least see 'something' from the nuget restore phase.

```
language: csharp
solution: src/Backoff.sln
install:
  - nuget # lets get version number
  - nuget restore src/Backoff.sln -Verbosity detailed
  - nuget update src/Backoff.sln -Verbosity detailed
```

Hopefully you get some info back and can update your answer here:

```
nuget restore src/Backoff.sln
Installing 'xunit 2.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit 2.0.0'.
Installing 'xunit.abstractions 2.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit.abstractions 2.0.0'.
Installing 'xunit.assert 2.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit.assert 2.0.0'.
Installing 'xunit.core 2.0.0'.
Installing 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit.core 2.0.0'.
Installing 'xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.0.1'.
Successfully installed 'xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.0.1'.

nuget update src/Backoff.sln -Verbosity detailed
Scanning for projects...
Found 1 project with a packages.config file. (Backoff.Tests)
Looking for installed packages in 'src/packages'.
Updating 'Backoff.Tests'...
GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xunit.runner.visualstudio'
GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xunit'
GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xunit.assert'
GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xunit.core'
GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xunit.extensibility.core'
GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='xunit.abstractions'
```

**Update:**

So using the fact that nuget 2.8.7 is being used by mono and the silent failure of restore and the error in the update phase it is a 'sub-directory failure' in nuget that is causing these. The solution directory is not the same as the Packages.config location and thus the silent failure is actually a hidden mono/.Net exception in Nuget.exe of System.InvalidOperationException of "Cannot determine the packages folder"

Updated yml that should install your xunit nugets:

```
language: csharp
solution: src/Backoff.sln
install:
  - nuget restore src/Backoff.Tests/Packages.config -SolutionDirectory src -Verbosity detailed
```

Note: This is not needed on OS-X as "nuget restore src" will work fine, but the full cmd listed above for Linux will also work fine on OS-X if you enable OS-X builds on Travis so no changes will be needed

Comment: I have this error now `NuGet.CommandLineException: Unable to locate the packages folder. Try specifying it using the repositoryPath switch.`

Comment: @Stan - I would try not running the `nuget update` command. Just the restore. That error is from the nuget update command which you were not originally using.

Comment: Still get error, https://travis-ci.org/stanislavromanov/backoff Any more info? Should it even work with C# projects?

Comment: Actually the 'nuget update' error message with the nuget version is the debug info that you need to solve the issue. Updated the answer.